# Best Data-access for SharePoint 2010 or 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

i want to know what's the best method to implementing of data access for SharePoint?

can i use Entity Framework for data access of SP2010 or 2007?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no the best method. You can choose the best one for current situation.
In both 2007 and 2010 versions you can use Server Object Model (in SP 2007 just Object Model) to operate with Sharepoint objects.
You can use CAML and LINQ (in SP2010 only) queries, or get data from web services (standard or custom).
Also in SP2010 you can use Client Object Model to operate with data on remote server.
I think the method you should use realy depends on situation.

Comment: i use CAML and LINQ in SharePoint 2010, but i want to know Can I use the Entity Framework for SP2010?